# The biggest positive integer which divides $f(n) - n\;\;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions

Let $f: \mathbb{N} -\mathbb{N}$ be a function defined by $f(x)=$biggest positive integer obtained by reshuffling the digits of $x$ . For example $f(296)=962$

Question:
Find the biggest positive integer which divides $f(n) - n \;\;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Do you want your biggest integer to divide $f(n)-n$ in every case? Or are you simply looking for the biggest possible $f(n)-n$?

Comment: It must be true for every value of n

Answer (score 2):

Let $k$ be the biggest positive integer which divides $f(n)-n$ for all positive integers $n$.

We have $f(12)=21$, so in this case $f(n)-n=9$. Hence $k\le9$.

$f(n)$ always has the same digit sum as $n$, so $f(n)-n$ must be a multiple of 9, so it is always divisible by 9. Hence $k=9$.

Comment: Why K is less than 9

Comment: @user346279 Because a bigger integer would not divide $f(12)-12=9$.